# How can I create a popup menu that allows user to choose a certain elements from a list on Java?

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a Java program to record some events and their status, i.e., done or not. I have implemented the recording and calculations, but I also want to have a button that will open another window that will list the events with a checkbox corresponding to each of them, so I can pick which ones' statuses I will change to done. I have only used Swing libraries so far.

I want this window to contain one event per line, with a checkbox next to the event. Each checkbox should determine whether the status of the even should be changed or not. I had trouble even making such a window open and list the items, let alone put the checkbox.

Note: The design is not too important. This won't be a published project, I will mostly use it for personal work. I can do with buttons instead of checkboxes, where any click changes the status of the event next to it.

Thank you in advance for your valuable responses.

Comment: The Oracle tutorial, [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) shows you how to use JCheckBoxes.  The Oracle tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) shows you how to complete a Swing GUI.

Comment: In my opinion, your question is [way too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this Web site. To open another window when a button is clicked, use `JDialog`. To display a list of strings with a `JCheckBox` next to each string, I suggest using a `JTable`. You can find more details in the tutorial linked to by @GilbertLeBlanc in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66873720/how-can-i-create-a-popup-menu-that-allows-user-to-choose-a-certain-elements-from#comment118211236_66873720) to your question.

Comment: Thank you Abra and Gilbert Le Blanc.

I think your comments should be sufficient.